# Git commits/merges losing code, reverts code from other people's commits

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-merge

We just started using Azure Devops and have been using a git repo to manage code. We have a number of developers committing code to the repo for the past two weeks since migration and have noticed that occasionally we get a commit that reverts files to previous state.

For example, if developer A and B commit code and then developer C commits, the developer C will get a merge commit and within that commit, we see code from A,B being reverted.

The devs are doing git pulls before committing so they should be up to date with remote before committing.

The merge commit we see that reverts changes is titled something along the lines of

Merge branch 'develop' of xxx into develop

Can you please help me understand what is causing this issue and how best to resolve it? Is there a recommended way of committing code in Visual studio using the git tooling?

Thanks
Amar Singh

Comment: Are your developers each working from individual branches, or from the same one?

Comment: Its the same branch.

Comment: This is usually developer error: a developer gets a message from Git saying that there is a merge conflict, and then the developer, instead of solving the merge conflict, commands Git to discard the other guy's code and use the developer's code instead. Git assumes that the developer knows what he is doing, obeys, and poof, the other code is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for replying torek. You are correct that this is a merge conflict issue. We had our suspicion that it down to being a merge conflict handling issue before I asked this question but couldn't understand why the reversion was being shown in the subsequent merge.

So here is what happens in our case:

Dev A,B commit and then Dev C gets into a merge conflict. They then merge the changes but unstage A,B work and only stage their work in. This results in a commit that shows Dev C's changes only but under the hood, git has reverted the A,B changes (**these aren't visible at this point**)

Then Dev D does a local commit and a git pull. This results in a second commit ("merge commit") being created. This is labeled as

Merge branch 'develop' of xxx into develop

When the Dev D pushes two commits up, the "merge branch" commit actually shows the changes from A,B being reverted. At first glance it looked like Dev D had done the wrong thing but it was in fact the Dev C.

So the message we will be giving to the devs is to handle merge conflicts carefully and not unstage anyone's work.

Thank you for your explanation.